# How can I modify the image item in Redactor to accept queryparams at the end of the src link programattically?

Tags: redactor

With my current setup, Craft is pointing images to a hosting service, and images loaded into redactor are setup to load images with that URL.

The service allows you to pass arguments at the end of the image link for things like compression.

What I'd like to do would be to add that argument at the end of the constructed link. Is there a way to do this automatically?